# Боковая панель за пределы окна. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

Хочу сделать выезжающую панель за пределы окна. Я написал код, но только панель меняет свои координаты, а главное окно не расширяется. Что я не так делаю?

Код:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ScriptOpen1">
    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="827" To="946" DecelerationRatio="0.9" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
</Storyboard>
```

С#:

```
Storyboard sb = Resources["ScriptOpen"] as Storyboard;
sb.Begin(scriptlist);

Storyboard sb1 = Resources["ScriptOpen"] as Storyboard;
sb1.Begin(this);
```

Comment: Анимацию можно запускать прямо в xaml при изменении `DepencyProperty` этого, или какого-нубдь другого контрола. С помощью `Binding`.

Comment: Какой смысл дергать постоянно размер окна? Вам за это ваши пользователи спасибо точно не скажут. Окно должно быть статично и только пользователь в праве управлять его размерами!

Answer (score 0):

Здесь банальная ошибка, у Window свойство Width имеет тип double, а не Thickness, поэтому данный код:

```
Storyboard sb1 = Resources["ScriptOpen"] as Storyboard;
sb1.Begin(this);
```

если this - это окно, работать не будет. Нужно использовать DoubleAnimation, тогда окно будет расширяться. Впрочем, выглядит постепенное расширение размеров окна довольно ущербно из-за мерцания черного фона.